Finding primes between interval repeats the same numbers many times
This is my code:
number1 = int(input("Enter The First Number "))
number2 = int(input("Enter The Second Number: "))


for number in range(number1, number2 + 1):
    if number > 1:
        for i in range(2, number):
            if (number % i) == 0:
                break
            else:
                print(number)

I wanted to see the results which are prime numbers to be shown, but what I've faced is this:
Enter The First Number 12
Enter The Second Number: 23
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
15
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
21
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23

As it can be seen, numbers have been repeating themselves a few times.

Note that 15 is being printed out. 15 is not a prime number. Try to figure out why 15 is being printed out. That should also help you find out why lots of other numbers are being printed out multiple times.

Once you have fixed the indentation as suggested in the answers, consider restricting your loop to the square root of number rounded down to an integer. Why? If there is a divisor a greater than sqrt(number) there must be another divisor b smaller than sqrt(number) so that a * b = number. You will always encounter b first in your loop. This reduces the complexity of identifying prime numbers from O(n) to O(sqrt(n)).

You need to change else condition inside for loop
The else block is aligned with the for loop, meaning it will only execute if the loop completes without encountering a break
number1 = int(input("Enter The First Number: "))
number2 = int(input("Enter The Second Number: "))

for number in range(number1, number2 + 1):
    if number > 1:  # Prime numbers are greater than 1
        for i in range(2, number):
            # If the number is divisible by any i, it's not prime
            if (number % i) == 0:  
                break
        else:
            print(number)

